# How can you increase the number of octaves for the Musgrave Texture in cycles?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I'm trying to use a musgrave texture (fBM), but there doesn't seem to be a setting to increase the number of octaves.

Does anyone have a node setup which can add more octaves to the musgrave texture?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_musgrave_texture.osl;d5d626df236b17c2d4ac731b2aaace52a2611304$202) the musgrave nodes detail value is kept between 0 and 16 and passed as the octave value for the noise function.

Comment: Is there a detail setting for cycles nodes?

Comment: It is the second number in the [node, under scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/musgrave.html).

Comment: The detail slider only seems to make increase the contrast of the texture.